# Laravel route ignore locale parameter

Tags: php, laravel

I have a locale middleware which is taking the first segment from the request and setting it as a locale:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $locale = $request->segment(1);
    session(['locale' => $locale]);
    app()->setLocale($locale);

    return $next($request);
}
```

Routes are afterwards defined behind a locale prefix like this:

```
Route::prefix('{lang}')->where(['lang' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'])->middleware('locale')->group(function () {
    Route::get('conversation/{from}/{to}', 'ConversationController@secureChatPage')->name('chat');
....
```

The issue I have now is that when I'm calling the method inside the `ConversationController` I can no longer do:

```
public function secureChatPage($from, $to)
{ ... }
```

Because `$from` parameter is taking the value of locale (e.g. `en`). This means that I would have to prepend method attributes with another variable `$locale`, and do so wherever the route parameter is needed.

Is there a clean way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no other way.

Laravel prefixes your route with all prefix values leading up to your route, regardless of whether those earlier prefixes are static text or slugs. Later, when the router dispatches the now resolved route, the slugs come along for the ride and are provided as arguments to your controller.

Per [the implementation](https://github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/master/Router.php#L552-L561):

```
/**
 * Prefix the given URI with the last prefix.
 *
 * @param  string  $uri
 * @return string
 */
protected function prefix($uri)
{
    return trim(trim($this->getLastGroupPrefix(), '/').'/'.trim($uri, '/'), '/') ?: '/';
}
```

I see the appeal of this simplification, but if it were done as you've requested, then those routes needing the prefix information would require an out-of-band accessor. That invokes the specter of injection, which is to be avoided.